# How to fetch data greater than a particular key value using pyrebase in firebase databse?

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I am developing a web service and is new to pyrebase.. I only want to fetch data from database having key greater than the particular value.
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v24A.png)

suppose I want to fetch data with key value greater than 154711668000 what should I write??

Answer (score 0):

To filter items based on their key, you use [`order_by_key`](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#order_by_key) and [`start_at`](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#start_at-and-end_at):

```
users_by_key = db.child("users").order_by_key().start_at("154711668000").get()
```

Comment: it gives "error" : "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path" ..My database looks like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fjr-EzrKr7JdYTpEKPpBzKxzaPTkjjnB/view?usp=sharing   and I am writing this code users_by_key = db.child("GPSData").child("08QEz10yBkg4jnfXyasSQjnlaqA2").order_by_key().start_at("1549711666000").get()

Comment: Hmm... I don't immediately see what's going wrong there. I got the syntax straight from the Pyrebase docs, so I'm not sure where that error is coming from.

Comment: it was arising due to this issue https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/294 . I have fixed it for now